# LinkedHashMap как заменить ключ оставив старую позицию?

Tags: java, коллекции

не могу придумать как заменить ключ оставив его на прежней позиции?
есть `LinkedHashMap<String, ...> map` задачей которой служит добавлять элементы поочередно и это важно, соответственно замена ключа по принципу удалить ключ и впихнуть новый приводит к тому, что элемент принимает последнюю позицию, оно и понятно почему, но вопрос как это можно обойти?

Comment: Ключ это хеш строки, его можно изменить изменив строку, если в этом вопрос.

Comment: а можно пожалуйста пример, а то немного не понимаю о чем вы?

Comment: [получения хэш-кода и индексов](https://habr.com/post/128017/) например.. но он не тривиально в яве организован, подразумевается при добавлении элемента, хеш получается автоматически с вводимого параметра (строка).

Answer (score 1):

Хороший вопрос. К сожалению сделать это невозможно, поскольку ни в интерфейсе `Map` ни в самом классе `LinkedHashMap` нет необходимого вам метода. То есть остаётся лишь полное копирование с заменой ключа во время копирования, но это, как вы наверное и сами понимаете, неэффективно.

Comment: Не соглашусь, почитайте еще раз спеки по map в java 8 - функция merge

Comment: Каким образом тут может помочь метод `merge()`? Вот вам код:
          LinkedHashMap<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();

        map.put("a1", "AAA");
        map.put("b1", "BBB");
        map.put("c1", "CCC");

Измените ключ `"a1"` на `"a2"` не изменяя порядок в `map`

Comment: Да пожалуйста - hashMap.merge("a1", "AAA", (k, v) -> "Test");
  hashMap.replace("b1", "BBB", "Test5");

Comment: @GenCloud вы не поняли исходный вопрос. Изменят нужно не `value` а сам `key`, то есть в моём примере `{a1=AAA, b1=BBB, c1=CCC}` нужно преобразовать в `{a2=AAA, b1=BBB, c1=CCC}`.